# Skipping the New Method in Controller (Go Right to the Create Method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I'd like to skip the "new" method in a controller entirely and go directly to the create method. (I don't need any form data to be submitted, and just want to go directly to creating the object based on data from the currently logged in user.)

In rake routes, I don't see a prefix that allows me to link directly to the controller's create method, so I think I should link to the new method and have that redirect to the create action without accepting any input.

I tried doing this with the following:

```
 def new
    create
 end

 def create
    @request = Request.new
    @request.requestor_id = current_user.id
    @request.status = "S1"
    @request.save

    respond_with(@request, :location => "/products/findexchanges")
 end
```

When browsing the DB, I can see that this is calling the create action and is adding the record to the db, but after it is done it is redirecting me to new.html.erb rather than the location defined at the end of the create method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `create` action should be triggered by a `POST`, not `GET`, which is why there is no specific route for it.

Comment: Ok, so I tried linking to the create method with <%= link_to "New Request", requests_path, :method=>:post %> but this is still redirecting me to new.html.erb. This time the create method isn't being invoked

Comment: You're close. Read carefully the doc of `link_to` on how to pass the `method` option.

Answer (score 1):

Use `button_to` instead of `link_to`. I tried using `link_to` and even after specifying `method: :post, action: :create`, it still takes me to index using GET. After using `button_to` and passing params in `####_path`, it directly went to the `create` method and added data to database. Although I am not sure its correct way or safe way to do this.